# What is route 66 in the context of DNS?

Tags: routing, dns

There is *route53* which in the context of AWS is their DNS service.

However, I've heard the term "route66" on different occasions in the context of DNS, but it never made sense to me.

I tried searching Google for what Route 66 is, but the answers are irrelevant, and the best I reached is that it's the name of an old road in the US.

Is there such a thing as "route66" in the context of DNS?

Comment: It's very likely a result of mis-remembering. Route53 is so-called because DNS goes over that port number and it sounds like the famous route. Route 66 has no technical meaning.

Comment: 3 years later, I'm re-reading my question and, of course, I can't believe I asked it hahaha! I was new to AWS and I asked this question because my client mentioned Route66, and it confused me. He ended up firing me because I asked him "What's Route66?", he thought that I don't know what DNS is, best decision he made because my career blossomed since then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are referring to port numbers. TCP and UDP (layer-4 protocols) use addresses, commonly called port numbers.

Both TCP and UDP use port 53 for DNS. If you want to know which port numbers are registered for which service, you can look in the [IANA Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml).

Type in any port number, and it will take you to the entries for that port.
 According to the port registry, port 66 is registered for `Oracle SQL*NET`.

If, on the other hand, you mean DHCP Option 66, that is for mass provisioning of VoIP phones. See [DHCP Options in Plain English](https://www.incognito.com/tips-and-tutorials/dhcp-options-in-plain-english/):

> Carries the FQDN or IP address (or cluster identifier) that the device
>   should use to download the file specified in option 67.  Note that
>   often the data put into option 66 does not actually appear in the DHCP
>   packet as option 66, but may have been moved into the “sname” field of
>   the DHCP packet.  Additionally, the FQDN may have been resolved to an
>   IP address and also placed in the “siaddr” field of the DHCP packet.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there such a thing as "route66" in the context of DNS?

**No**

AWS supposedly named the service Route 53 because all DNS requests are handled through port 53. So when you open up DNS to the world you do it on port 53.

The "route" piece resembles the historic "Route 66" of the USA. But it does not have a special significance in terms of networking.